# I was trying to access the database from my python program but getting error for the connection

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy   
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql://root:@localhost/digifit"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

'''class is the table created in the database'''
class Details(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(8), unique=True, nullable=False)
@app.route("/login",methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if request.method=='POST':
        '''add entry to the database'''
        username=request.form.get('username')
        Password=request.form.get('password')
        entry = Details(username=username,password=Password)
        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("login.html")
```

this is the code for the program . I am using flask sql alchemy.
The error I am getting on submiting information on login page created is :
1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8

Comment: you have permission error to the database. check your password. Somethimes the empty password works for root user(on MySQL, not sure about your db)

Comment: i have not set any password for the database